# is it possible to pass custom query string through dynamic link(google firebase)?

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I have been thinking an event that gives rewards to users who share our media contents with potential users. The reward would be given to the one clicked the link(not app installation).

To verify, I need to embed sharer's id in dynamic link. I did check its official docs but couldn't find any...

Would you please give me some solutions worth trying?

Answer (score 0):

You could set the referral information in the deep link of your FDL. Here's an example of a link with custom data appended on the deeplink (https://example.page.link/?link=https://links.example.com?d=value&apn=com.starcloud.example.develop&isi=123456789&ibi=com.example.example).

With this setup, "referral/data '' could be fetched in the app using Dynamic Links SDK.

You could also check this [guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/use-cases/rewarded-referral#create_invitation_links) on rewarding user referrals using Dynamic Links, which also makes use of [Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database) to track referrals and referees and [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions) to give the referral rewards. This tutorial doesn't cover a system for subsequent referrals from former referees, but it should give you a good idea on what an implementation for this would look like.